# Rust image::SubImage, no method named `put_pixel` found for type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

The following code

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
image = "0.23.6"
```

**src/main.rs**

```rust
extern crate image;
use image::*;
    
fn main() {
    let mut img: RgbImage = ImageBuffer::new(512, 512);

    let a = SubImage::new(img, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    a.put_pixel(Rgb::from_channels(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Produces the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `put_pixel` found for type `image::SubImage<image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:7
  |
8 |     a.put_pixel(Rgb::from_channels(0, 0, 0, 0));
  |       ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `image::SubImage<image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>>`
  |
  = note: the method `put_pixel` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `image::SubImage<image::ImageBuffer<image::Rgb<u8>, std::vec::Vec<u8>>> : image::GenericImage`
```

Why is that? `SubImage` clearly implements `GenericImage`. What should I do to use [`SubImage::put_pixel()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.6/image/struct.SubImage.html)?

Comment: Did the answer help or does it need more clarification?

Comment: @Jason Oops sorry. It totally worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `SubImage` clearly implements `GenericImage`. What should I do to use `put_pixel()`?

The `impl` for [`GenericImageView`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.6/src/image/image.rs.html#832-862) is what you can access due to an immutable reference being passed.

The `impl` for [`GenericImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.6/src/image/image.rs.html#864-902) can be accessed by passing a mutable reference in the following ways:

```rust
let mut sub_image = SubImage::new(&mut img, 0, 0, 1, 1);
```

```rust
let mut sub_image = SubImage::new(img.inner_mut(), 0, 0, 1, 1);
```

More idiomatically, the [`sub_image()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.6/image/trait.GenericImage.html#method.sub_image) method can be used, given that `img` is mutable:

```rust
let mut sub_image = img.sub_image(0, 0, 1, 1);
```